# Relative layout with Button and image view not working above 21.0

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am facing issue that if i run the same code with relative layout on 4.1 it is working fine but above 21.0 it is not working and image view hidden below the button with "Match_Parent"
here is my code :

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_select_pod"
                style="@style/basic_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
                android:text="Select POD Media " />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:focusable="true" />


        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is your button style the same on 21+?

Comment: thanks @oppoo i found the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue and now image is shown by putting the elevation in the `imageview` with `2dp`.

```
android:elevation="2dp"
```

Now the final code will be

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_select_pod"
            style="@style/basic_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
            android:text="Select POD Media " />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:focusable="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it will work for you also.